# JavaScript | Why variable is overridden retroactively

Tags: javascript

In my application, I am logging an array of objects trying to understand where `a` gets populated:

```
[
    {
        a: []
    },
    {
        a: []
    }
]
```

I noticed that, when I log the object as soon as it is built (and it's empty) I receive something like this:

```
[
    {
        a: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
        a: [1, 2, 3]
    }
]
```

I tried to put a `debugger` immediately after the log and `a`s were empty as expected.
My guess is that `a` is populated later, but this reflects on the log. Why does this happen?